# LangChain: How to avoid having the input as part of the out when invoking a chain?

Tags: langchain

I am in the process of doing my master's thesis and will focus on multi-agent systems for software testing. I have decided to use LangGraph as my framework of choice and I am in the process of learning it.

I have been toying around with LangChain and it's been working great. However, one of the things that I cannot seem to figure out, is how to have the model only give me the output, without the input being a part of it.

Code example below:

```
llm_hf = HuggingFaceHub(
    repo_id="mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2",
    model_kwargs={"temperature": 0.9}
)

duck_specialist_template = """
I want you to act as a specialist in ducks, covering aspects from their biology to conservation.

Your role involves providing expert insights into different duck species, including their habitats, behaviors, and the challenges they face in their natural environments. Additionally, you're tasked with advising on conservation strategies to protect these species and their habitats from threats such as habitat loss, pollution, and climate change.

For any inquiry about ducks, offer a comprehensive overview that includes species identification, habitat preferences, dietary habits, migratory patterns, and conservation status. Moreover, suggest practical conservation measures that can be implemented to support the health and sustainability of duck populations.

Can you provide funny name suggestions on a duck that looks like {duck_description}?

"""

tiny = "a small, energetic duck with bright blue feathers and a penchant for doing somersaults in the water. Its quack is surprisingly deep for its size"

prompt_template = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["duck_description"],
    template=duck_specialist_template,
)


chain = LLMChain(llm=llm_hf, prompt=prompt_template)

print(chain.run(duck_description=tiny))
```

Now, when I run this it gives me the following output:

> I want you to act as a specialist in ducks, covering aspects from their biology to conservation.
>
> Your role involves providing expert insights into different duck species, including their habitats, behaviors, and the challenges they face in their natural environments. Additionally, you're tasked with advising on conservation strategies to protect these species and their habitats from threats such as habitat loss, pollution, and climate change.
>
> For any inquiry about ducks, offer a comprehensive overview that includes species identification, habitat preferences, dietary habits, migratory patterns, and conservation status. Moreover, suggest practical conservation measures that can be implemented to support the health and sustainability of duck populations.
>
> Can you provide funny name suggestions on a duck that looks like a small, energetic duck with bright blue feathers and a penchant for doing somersaults in the water. Its quack is surprisingly deep for its size?
>
> Absolutely! Based on the description you've given, I would suggest the name "Flippy the Feisty Blue Bunter." This name captures the duck's small size, energetic nature, bright blue feathers, and acrobatic behavior in the water (somersaults), while the "feisty" part adds a fun and lively character to its name. The term "bunter" is a playful way to refer to the duck's

Here the prompt is part of the output, which in turn cuts off the models response. I have been trying to find out a way to fix this, but prompting does not seem to work and I could not find anything that works online.